# Runtime error, makes my .exe crash and I am not sure why

Tags: c++, runtime-error, int64, uint64

I can take a guess that it has something to do with working with the unsigned long long int.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long int uint64;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    uint64 number_in_question = 600851475143LL;

    long double sqrt_in_question = sqrt(number_in_question);
    bool primes_array[number_in_question+1];



    for (uint64 i = 0; i <= number_in_question; i++) {
        primes_array[i] = true;
    }

    for (uint64 i = 2; i <= sqrt_in_question; i++) {
        if(primes_array[i] == true) {
            // for every multiple of this prime, mark it as not prime
            for (uint64 ii = i*2; ii <= number_in_question; ii += i) {
                primes_array[ii] = false;           
            }
        }
    }   

    for (uint64 i = 0; i <= number_in_question; i++) {
        if(primes_array[i] == true)
        cout << i << ", ";
    }


    system("PAUSE");


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit1:
Some background of what I am trying to do:

I am trying to mimic this technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
while I am using an array to store a simple "is it prime" 1 for yes, 0 for no. The end goal is to solve this:

`What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?` Listed here: http://projecteuler.net/problem=3.  I am just working on the primes and then will work on the prime factors.

Edit2:

Upon looking at the Wikipedia link I posted, I realized they have puesdocode (skipped over that and came up with what I have) and realized that had this note: 
Large ranges may not fit entirely in memory. In these cases it is necessary to use a segmented sieve where only portions of the range are sieved at a time.[14] For ranges so large that the sieving primes could not be held in memory, space-efficient sieves like that of Sorenson are used instead.
Therefore I will have to think of a way to do this using a "segmented sieve" method.

Edit3:

Changed the array to account for the [0] element so the "issue" is only focused on the array memory size being too large for future references; also stored the array as a bool instead of a uint64.

Comment: Why do you suspect `unsigned long long int` to be the culprit? Have you run the application in a debugger? What is the offending line?

Comment: Dev-C++ isn't letting me debug it correctly. Haven't worked with C++ in a while just downloaded a compiler (bloodshed dev-C++) and running into the issue. Perhaps I'll try another compiler.

Comment: `uint64 primes_array[number_in_question];` - does that actually compile? The number_in_question is a runtime variable, not define or enum.
Also, the code `for (uint64 i = 0; i <= number_in_question; i++)` goes beyond the array dimensions, you should allocate it like this: `uint64 primes_array[] = new uint64[number_in_question + 1];`

Comment: @Pelya: Gcc has an extension to allow c dynamic sized arrays in c++, so it might.

Comment: @Pelya Yeah Window's bloodshed dev-C++ allowed me to have variable bounds to the array.

Comment: While implementing a segmented sieve is a good idea in general, it's not a good approach for this question. Even if you go with a sieve for it, you need only sieve to the square root of `number_in_question`. But even that will do way more work than necessary for this question.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info

Comment: @Daniel, Yes I had to give in and google other's answers to the problem and realized more simple ways.

Comment: @Fred I didn't realize it was looked down upon, though my C++ teacher back in 2004 suggested it as the best thing...and it was one of the first matches for "C++ compiler" on google. I am getting code blocks now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to allocate an `uint64` array of length `600851475143`. For 8 byte `uint64` that means this array will take up `600851475143*8byte` which is roughly `4.5TB` of memory. Even if your system can allocate  that much memory (unlikely) you are trying trying to put it on the stack which has typically a size bound to only a few MB. Furthermore you are trying to write to index `number_in_question`, while the last index in the array is `number_in_question-1`.

Comment: 4.5TB memory, I wish. It makes sense. Also, bloodshed never gave me an error with the last index thing but I realize I must define the array as + 1 as it has the 0th element.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume your are blowing the stack when it attempts to create the array.  That size of array is tremendously large and would have to be created on the heap to even have a chance of succeeding.

Comment: Yes, I have same opinion, this array will be created on stack, but you can not have stack of this size

Comment: You'll even have trouble on the heap. Few boxes come with over 4TB of RAM+swap nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has "number_in_question" elements, numbered 0 to number_in_question - 1. But, your for loop will try to access primes_array[number_in_question], which is outside the available space, if that large of an array will even be allocated to you.

Why are you allocating an array of uint64 and storing either 0 or 1 in each element?

Edit: also, you can't allocate an array on the stack with a variable size like that. You'd have to use new to allocate that space on the heap. Again, assuming your system will allow you to allocate that much space.

Comment: You are right, for some reason I thought having a uint64 amount of elements would require uint64 type but the array should be defined as a bool. This was fixed in edit 3.